# Why does custom NSView redraw when window is resized or moved (drag) to an secondary display (monitor)?

Tags: macos, nsview, xcode10, swift4.2, redraw

I recently started adding graphic charts to a MacOS application I wrote. The first chart is great and I added a second chart where I ran into a fundamental way the code operates that I did not/do not understand. The only reason I ran into this is because in my second chart I used random to draw some bubbles inside confined areas. It works nicely but when I resized the view window a little bit the chart redrew everything and since I was using random the first set of bubbles remained in the screen and the second set were added to the screen. So I made a simple example to illustrate.

```
class GraphView: NSView {
    var dcnt = 0

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        dcnt+=1
        print(dcnt)
        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
        var rec = NSRect()
        var circ = NSBezierPath()

        NSColor.lightGray.setFill()
        path.fill()

        rec = NSRect(x:Int.random(in: 100...900), y:Int.random(in: 70...560), width:50, height:50)
        NSColor.red.setFill()
        circ = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: rec)
        circ.fill()
        circ.stroke()
    }
}
```

This is run from a simple ViewController that calls the GraphView. I added a counter to print out and see what is happening. Also, if I drag the chart/view window over to a second monitor, it also forces a redraw.

How do I stop this from happening. I want to draw the chart and that is it. No clicking, dragging, resizing (I have disabled resizing the window) should redraw anything.

Here is an example of what happens when I drag the chart to a secondary monitor...

[image]

Comment: Does the view or one of its superviews resize when the window is resized?

Comment: @Willeke. In the testing I am doing I turned that ability off in Interface Builder for both the ViewController and the Custom View and the problem persists when I drag the window/view over to a second monitor. When I drag back to the first monitor it happens again. Originally in my app the bubble chart is in I disabled resizing in the ViewController with self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(NSWindow.StyleMask.resizable) in ViewDidAppear(). That worked, until I moved the chart to another monitor.

Comment: @Willeke And resizing of the chart itself is not an aspect of my code. I just want to write once and do not need the chart to stretch and grow or shrink as the window is resized. I do want to learn how to do that but not now. I am now pushing further into working with Contexts and investigating writing to a PDF for static viewing.

Comment: I have sorted out the issue I was experiencing with the multiple duplicates in my bubble chart above. And now that I have worked with Contexts I understand why dragging a chart/view over to another display forces a redraw. I would still like to know if there is a way to stop this. I think also that I will be able to work differently when I finally move to Big Sur and the macos implementation of UIKit. So, I will leave this open for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does custom NSView redraw when window is resized or moved (drag) to an secondary display (monitor)?

A window resize causes view resizes. The secondary display may have a different resolution.

> How do I stop this from happening.

You can't, `draw` is called multiple times.

> I want to draw the chart and that is it.

Create a `NSImage` of the chart and display it in a `NSimageView`.

> the first set of bubbles remained in the screen and the second set were added to the screen

Calculate the coordinates or rect of the circle once when the view is created so `draw` will always draw the same circle.